# Can I switch SVN repositories from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am moving my Subversion repository from one machine to another.  I have a few scattered working copies on various machines, and I have found that I can easily switch the working copies from the old server to the new one with the following command:

```
svn --relocate svn://oldServer/repo svn://newServer/repo
```

However, on one of my machines, I use Eclipse with Subclipse, and I don't like to use command-line SVN on my Eclipse projects.  My question is whether it is possible to switch SVN repositories from within Eclipse using either Subclipse or Subversive.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I think you need to go into your 'repository browser' perspective there you right click your current repository and 'relocate' it to another domain.

Comment: This worked perfectly on the box I had running Subclipse, and something very similar worked on the box with Subversive.  The trick on Subversive turned out to be modifying the "location properties" in the repository browser.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Subversive is not capable of relocation across protocols. Going from SVN+SSH to HTTPS seems impossible, keeps constructing the SVN+SSH URL and requesting credentials for it. How is it with Subclipse?

Comment: Note, you need to open any existing projects using the old repository, since the "relocate" command will only update open projects. This is important, because after you relocate, it's not easy to run relocate again on any closed projects you missed. I made this mistake and had to wipe out my closed projects and re-checkout.

Comment: @Ain, It worked flawlessly for me with Subclipse 1.6 in Eclipse 3.7. However, be sure to setup passwordless SSH access to your remote server. Otherwise Subclipse will prompt you each time for your password, since it's relying solely on the local SSH client.

Comment: @Cerin: good tips thanks, will give it a try next time I'm on it, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Do not use the "Team/switch" option, but rather change to the "SVN repository exploring" perspective and change the URL location there in the location properties of your repository. Works like a charm on Indigo - using Subversive in my case.

When using Subversive this will show a warning *"The attached projects will be relocated because the repository root URL differs from the previously entered one"*, which is just what you want. Be sure to open all projects you want relocated before doing this.

[image]

When getting *"Cannot relocate the connected projects"* with *"Relocation cannot be performed because the new URL refers to the different repository"* then maybe your repository root has no trunk/tags/branches folders, or has such folders in subfolders as well. Then on the tabsheet Advanced, disabling the option Enable Structure Detection might help.

If you get *"Relocation cannot be performed because the new URL refers to the repository which is not valid (incorrect URL or credentials specified)"* then also make sure the root path within the new repository URL matches the root of the old URL. (In other words: ensure that `/new/path` in the screenshot above has the same subfolders as the old URL.)

Comment: This is the correct answer with newer Eclipse installations.

Answer (score 13):

Just right click on the project-> team -> disconnect.

Then another right click on the project -> team -> share -> to your new SVN.

That's it!

Answer (score 4):

Within Eclipse Navigator, if you right-click the project name a submenu will appear.  On that sub-menu select Team which will provide some addtional menu options.  Select the "Swich to another Branch/Tag/Revision ..." and a window will appear allowing you to specify the new branch or in your case a new repository location.

Comment: I have the privilege to comment, so I will point out that Stefan's comment below (and Luke's accepted answer above) are correct.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work: SVN Swtich has encountered a problem. org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: ... is not the same repository as ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

Go to project explorer view -> right click on your project -> team -> switch  ... and now select the new URL.

Thats all!

Comment: This will not work, since the hostname is different and it will complaint saying that it couldnt find the hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

I could not relocate from my eclipse. I have different projects on different branches and tags (read-only it’s only for comparing different versions) of the same repository. When the ip of our svn server changed, I could relocate through TortoiseSVN but not from Subclipse.

Changing from `http://oldserver/svn/PROJECTNAME` to `http://newserver/svn/PROJECTNAME` I get :

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.CientException: Invalid operation on the current working directory
svn: Cannot relocate 'E:\…\workspaces\PROJECTNAME\tags\modulename\2.4.007\base' as it is not the root of a working copy; try relocating 'E:\…\workspaces\PROJECTNAME\tags\modulename\2.4.007' instead
```

Ok but I don’t have the control over this. I ended with a workaround involving my hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, go to Window -> Perspective -> Open Perspective -> Other -> SVN Repository Exploring. Click Ok

Then right click on the repository you want to change -> Location Properties.

Change the url click finish.

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

- disconnect project in eclipse from `team` menu
  (without clean information from file system)
- go to hidden folder `.svn`
- open file `wc.db` with SQLite editor
- change the value of unique row present in `REPOSITORY` table with new url
- re-share the project from `team` menu

Eclipse checks only the connection to the repository and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just swap the server names in DNS; this might be easier than switching all the working copies.

Answer (score 0):

team -> disconnect

and

team -> share -> to your new SVN

This is better solution than switch.