# (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY During Committing on Google Code

Tags: svn, google-code

I was uploaded my code to code.google and successfully committed two times but now when ever i try to commit my code it always gives

```
Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY
```

i can still successfully checkout my project but when i made little change in a file and than try to commit it, It always gives same error now. i was trying SVNTrotoise i even clear its temporary data in /user/AppData/SVN... but still same problem. I tried to commit my project from MAC terminal and still same error.

On internet i searched this error and they says that it is dew to a folder which you are trying to add and that already exist but in my case i even tried to commit my project right after checking out and making a little change in single file

Comment: This thread says how to relocate in eclipse.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679585/can-i-switch-svn-repositories-from-eclipse

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After Alot of search after all i found answer on google code itself when i checkout my project i was checkout it with http://repUrl.com and than when i try to commit it it was giving that error. If you want to commit a project after checkout you have to checkout it with https://repoUrl.com instead of http://repoUrl.com

Comment: Thanks so much for answering your own question! Really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Solution for code.google.com is relocating the svn local copy to https url.

and next try to commit again. For me worked.