# update SVN Repositories URL in Current Project in ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I created a SVN repository on the VisualSVN Server. I use this repository from my desktop computer in Eclipse IDE over the Internet using HTTPS protocol. Everything was working fine until now.

SUDDENLY, I have to change the server's domain name,for example previously it was `domain.org` and now I have to make it `domain.info` for some reason.

So **how would I update the repository URL** which was previously assigned to some of the project in Eclipse IDE so it will point to the new target server?

### EDIT (because of Survivor of SO and so called experts)

i tried the solution as suggested in comments those users give me who themselves treat them superior to other users on SO and treat themselves as an survivor of SO, it gives me following error shown in screen shot

[image: error relocating SVN repository]

so what do i do now ?
those users who voted to close this question can answer my question ?

**i think those who can not answer the question have no rights to edit some one's question nor have rights to close the question.**

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I switch SVN repositories from Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679585/can-i-switch-svn-repositories-from-eclipse)

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979872/svn-switch-with-relocate-in-eclipse

Comment: @bahrep i have updated the question now answer my question if you can.

Comment: please don't be offended! This is how StackExchange sites and StackOverflow works. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

Answer (score 1):

The error on the screenshot means that you enter incorrect repository URL to relocate to. The URL `https://190dev.no-ip.info:8443/svn/` points to a repositories list, not a repository.

I suppose that you want to enter something like this: `https://190dev.no-ip.info:8443/svn/<repository-name>`.

Comment: i tried all above things but it could not work, so finally i disconnect project from svn. now, can you tell me how can i re connect the existing project to .info location ?